# Converting string range into date type in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have a string column which name is player. This is a string range column

Column:   Rows
Player : 2014-2015, 2015-2016,2017-2018,2018-2019

I want to convert this string type to date type.

I tried dateparse('yyyy-yyyy',[player]) function but it gives null value.

Is there anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you would need to choose a date to represent these values. For example you may want 2014-2015 to be a 1/1/2014. Up to you which date works best.

Use either LEFT or RIGHT to extract the year you want. For example, to extract 2014 from the first field use this:

```
LEFT([FieldName],4)
```

Then use the MAKEDATE function to convert to a date value. To convert to a date, using the 1/1/2014 example:

```
MAKEDATE(INT(LEFT([FieldName],4)),1,1)
```